# Find values for probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For what value of $C$ and $m$ can the following function be probability density function?

$$f(x)=C(1+x^2)^{-m}$$

Comment: What did you try? It is appropriate to include your effort on solving a problem so that others can give you feedback and guide you to the answer rather than just give it to you.

Comment: I have tried calculating the integral but failed. I substituted $x$ with $tan\theta$

Answer (score 2):

A probability density function is given by two properties:

1) $f(x) \geq 0$

2) $\int f(x) = 1$

Clearly, $C >0$ is required to satisfy (1) [and =0 would clearly violate 2].

To check (2), calculate out the integral and set it equal to 1. Using that, find a relation between C, m to get valid pairs of C,m such that (2) holds. Note that there are many such answers (for example, m=2 and C=$2 / \pi$, $m=1$ and $C=1/\pi$, etc.).

Assuming the density is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, if you look at $(1+x^2)^{-m}$, this indicates $\int f(x)$ is finite if and only if $m > 1/2$ (by comparing the tails to $1/x^{m/2}$). Thus, the $(C,m)$ pairs are given by $(\frac{1}{\int_\mathbb{R} (1+x^2)^{-m} dx}, m)$ for $m > 1/2$.

Comment: I know the general procedure, but I failed at calculating the integral.

Comment: I've updated with a little bit more of a hint. But show the work you've done thusfar.

Comment: I didn't realize $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^m}dx$ is finite if $m>0$. And $m>0$ because otherwise the integral would never be finite.

Comment: If your density is defined on $[0,1]$, its finite for all $m$ -- $(1+x^2)^{-m}$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$ in this case.